# How to run The Castle Doctrine in fullscreen?

Tags: the-castle-doctrine

Alt+Enter doesn't do the trick and there seems to be no options menu. Is there maybe a command line switch? Or, as a last resort, any external tool which allows one to fullscreen the current window?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As described [here](http://thecastledoctrine.net/forums/viewtopic.php?pid=6563#p6563), simply change the `0` in the `settings\fullscreen.ini` to a `1` and you're done. As an aside, the files `screenHeight.ini` and `screenWidth.ini` let you choose the resolution (or window size).